# Integral of sine multiplied by zeroth-order Bessel function with complicated arguments

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

How to find the solution to this integral:

$$\int_0^a J_0\left(b\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\right)\ \sin{c x}\ \mathrm{d}x$$

I found a similar integral, but instead of the sine is a cosine function in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's book, section 6.677, equation number 6.

$\int_0^a J_0\left(b\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\right)\ \cos{c x}\ \mathrm{d}x=\frac{\sin\left(a\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\right)}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}$
for $b > 0$

Any help and hints will be appreciated

Comment: Hint: get rid of the useless $a$ parameter, then switch to Fourier transforms.